# Discord.py get user object from id/tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm using the [`discord.py`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) library to build a discord bot. I'm trying to get a [`User`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.User) object from an id or tag, however, I am using a user account instead of a bot account, so I can't use `get_user_info()`. Is there any way to do this on a user account?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you know the user id, I suggest using [`bot.get_user(user_id)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_user) instead.

Comment: olny works if the cache has it. use fetch_user otherwise

Answer (score 9):

If you're using `commands`, you can use a converter:

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def mycommand(ctx, user: discord.User):
    # user is a User object
```

Other wise, you can use [`Client.get_all_members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_all_members) to get all [`Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member) objects you can see.

```py
from discord.utils import get

user = get(bot.get_all_members(), id="1234")
if user:
    # found the user
else:
    # Not found the user
```

Comment: The id is guilds ids or user id?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```py
ctx.message.server.get_member(id) or message.server.get_member(id) # id must be of type int
```

This will return you a [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#member) object.

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#member

Answer (score 2):

This also will return your user object, but not your member object. If you want the member object, please follow [AJ Lee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67954572/5434263)

```py
user = await client.fetch_user(user_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the id, call `user = await ctx.bot.fetch_user(user_id)`. No messing about with permissions.

If you only have the username and tag, you can use:

```py
guild.fetch_members()
user = guild.get_member_named("Example#1234")
```

Note you'll also need to turn the Members intent on in your code and the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) in order to call `fetch_members()`

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
super().__init__(
  command_prefix='!',
  intents=intents
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
ctx.message.server.get_member(id) or message.server.get_member(id)
```

I couldn't write a comment to the previous answer (because of reputation) but make sure that id is [int type here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_member).

Answer (score 0):

For me, only this worked, so if none of the others worked you could try this:

```py
user = await message.guild.query_members(user_ids=[userid]) # list of members with userid
user = user[0] # there should be only one so get the first item in the list
```

Answer (score 0):

**Okay so there are many ways to do so but I use this**

```py
@commands.command()
async def id(self, ctx, *, user_id):
    user = ctx.message.guild.get_member(user_id) or None
    if user != None:
        # Found the user
        ctx.send(user)
    else:
        # Can't find the user
        ctx.send("**Try that again**, this time add a user's id(**of this server**)")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want for exaple to send a message to a sepcific user than this should do:

```
@bot.command()   
async def test(ctx)
    user = bot.get_user(userid)
    await user.send("Example")
```