# PMing multiple users when command is used

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a command in a bot that will allow people with specific roles to reward other users with currency. I am trying to have it setup so that when the command is used, the bot will send a DM to the user notifying them of the reward, and then send a DM to myself (the owner of the bot) to inform me of the action, and why it was given.

I have a file setup that has a dictionary that relates user name to userID. So when you type, for example: `!rewardgold 100 Joe'`, it takes 'joe' and looks it in the database to see if an ID is associated to it. In this regard, I already have Joe's unique userID, and I obviously have my own. So it should just be a matter of sending that DM to each person. I currently have it using `ctx.send()` in the code below for completions sake, but the desire is to replace that with the DM to both people.

Also `@commands.has_role("Admin")` is commented out because despite the username I am testing this on having the role of 'Admin' using the command always errors out. This is in a script: `BotCommands.py`

```py
import os
import json

import asyncio
from pathlib import Path
from collections import Counter

from discord.ext import commands

from gamelogic import onMSGAccept, onMSGRoll, onMSGUtil, onPRIUtil

class Combat(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    #!rewardgold <gold> <player> <reason> (If no reason given, defaults to "Not Specified")
    @commands.command()
    @commands.dm_only()
    #@commands.has_role("Admin")
    async def rewardgold(self, ctx, gold, player, reason="Not Specified"):

        msg = ""
        charFolder = characters()

        with open(charFolder + "playerDatabase.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8") as file2:
            playerDatabase = json.loads(file2.read())
            file2.close()
        try:
            gifted = ""
            for item in playerDatabase.items():
                if item[0].lower() == player.lower():
                    gifted = item[1]

            giftedFile = open(charFolder + str(gifted) + ".txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
            giftedData = json.load(giftedFile)
            giftedFile.close()
            giftedData['gold'] += int(gold)
            file = open(charFolder + str(gifted) + ".txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
            json.dump(giftedData, file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
            file.close()
            await ctx.send(player + " has been awarded  " + str(gold) +
                           " gold. (Reason: " + reason)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            await ctx.send(player + " does not have a character.")
```

I have tried to do my homework, but everything I google revolves around the use of `Client.send_message`, which has been discontinued in discord.py rewrite in favor of just send(). I am unsure of how to use `.send()` to send the message to Joe's uniqueID, and not back to the person that used the command in the first place.

I also looked in to an event that holds `on_message`, but again, my google fu only shows examples of that working in a very simplistic manner in channel rooms. Said examples always being of listening to the room, seeing a message typed, and spitting it back out into the room again. This isn't helpful. My bot initiation script `botCreation.py` is as follows:

```py
import discord
import os
import json

from discord.ext import commands

with open('token.txt', 'r+') as file:
    stuff = json.load(file)
    file.close()
token = stuff["token"]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')
client.remove_command('help')

@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    client.load_extension("cogs." + extension)

@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension("cogs." + extension)

@client.command()
async def reload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension("cogs." + extension)
    client.load_extension("cogs." + extension)

for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension("cogs." + filename[:-3])

client.run(token)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54499864/discord-py-get-user-object-from-id-tag and https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_user look useful

Comment: I feel like they are. It's basically like slapping me in the face with the answer, but I still can't get it to work in practice. I presume it is because I don't have something properly imported into the script? I have edited my main post to show what is imported in each ```.py``` file, as well as ```botCommand.py```'s ```__init__``` method. I don't know it it will be of more or less help.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have `dm_only`, and `has_role` on the same command.  `has_role` checks for roles in the guild the command is issued in, and private messages aren't associated with a particular guild.

Comment: I agree. In my efforts to figure out the main problem, I realized this mistake as well and have thus removed it.

Comment: This answer in the first link looks like exactly what you want https://stackoverflow.com/a/54609616/2372812

Comment: client.get_user_id in the second link also looks like it might work for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/54609616/2372812

Comment: I added in `user = discord.Client.get_user(gifted)` to the sccript, and get `discord.Client.get_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'` Isn't get_user() only suppose to take in on variable? the unique ID, which the variable 'gifted' holds?