# DM to a person by user id in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have checked a lot of answers, but those answers use `ctx.author.send('something')`. But I want to send by user ID, not AUTHOR.

This is my code:

```
@bot.command()
async def dm(ctx):
    await ctx.send(496021236988510209, 'test')
```

And it doesn't even return an error message.

Comment: If it doesn't return an error message, what is the problem? What did you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py get user object from id/tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54499864/discord-py-get-user-object-from-id-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a member of your server use [Guild.get_member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_member).

There is also [Client.fetch_user](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fetch#discord.Client.fetch_user) which only works on bots.

If it should be working but no members are showing up it is most likely because you forgot to state your intentions of using `members` before creating your discord client. For example:

```py
import discord
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Possible duplicate, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54499864/discord-py-get-user-object-from-id-tag/55967167).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following code:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles = True)
async def dm(ctx, users: Greedy[User], *, message):
    for user in users:
      await user.send(message)
```

You just do dm @3422353423342 message

@3422353423342 represents a users id

Comment: Quality answers usually include an explanation as to how/why essential bits of your answer solves the OP's question. An `edit` may clarify use for future visitors so l they earn something to apply to their own coding issues. This is how most upvotes are obtained over time.  Generally code only Answers are discouraged. You can edit and/or keep in mind for future posts.