# discord.py can you get a user object from discord tag?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Can I get a discord user object from a discord tag eg: discorduser#0001?

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54499864/discord-py-get-user-object-from-id-tag/55967167

Comment: @gtbell511 from what i am seeing on that thread is how to get a user object from their discord id not their discord tag which is what im trying to do, however i might be wrong

Comment: @Nurqm I don't have any code yet as i am trying to figure out how i would get a object from a discord tag i know how i could do it with an id `user = await client.fetch_user([userid) ` but im trying to get it from a tag user#0001 i am not sure how i would do that.

Answer (score 0):

The [discord.py documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_user) describes the method `get_user(id)` of the `discord.Client` class.

This can probably be added to the simple example on the [Github page for discord.py](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/new_member.py) like the following (not tested):

```
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged in as')
        print(self.user.name)
        print(self.user.id)
        print('------')
        self.get_user(id)

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = MyClient(intents=intents)
client.run('token')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`discord.ext.commands.MemberConverter`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.MemberConverter) to convert ids, names, nicknames, mentions and name#discriminator to a `discord.Member` object.

```py
from discord.ext.commands import MemberConverter

converter = MemberConverter()
member = await converter.convert(ctx, 'discorduser#0001')
```