# Discord.py: How do I get a user from a UserID?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I need my bot to get a user from a UserID. I tried it like this:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '&')

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def test(ctx, id : int):
  user = client.get_user(id)
  print(user)

TOKEN = ""
client.run(TOKEN)
```

but it always returns None, but why? :C Thanks for helping.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py get user object from id/tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54499864/discord-py-get-user-object-from-id-tag)

Comment: No, nothing in that post works for me.

Comment: A command is made to be run by a user, otherwise make it a regular function.

Comment: I added the actuall code to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
async def test(id: int):
    user = client.get_user(id)

    if user is None: # Maybe the user isn't cached?
        user = await client.fetch_user(id) 

    return user

# Inside the loop
user = await test(12312312313)
```

Also remember to enable `intents.members`, [here's how](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html)

Comment: Yea so like I said I can't use context, because it won't be executed by a user and also I tried defining it as an Integer and it didn't work.

Comment: There's no way of invoking a command without the context. How are you "calling" the command then?

Comment: I call it from a task.loop every 10 seconds.

Comment: And why does it need to be a command then? Can't it be a normal coroutine?

Comment: I want the bot to give me a leaderboard but I only log the userID and I don't want that showing up in the leaderboard.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question

Comment: Im not to experienced with Discord.py so I dont really know why I couldn't be one. So whats your advise then? If it can be a corutine.

Comment: Put it as a normal async function and call it inside the loop, there's no need to make it a command

Comment: Well I did exactly that, I just made it like this to be more understandable.

Comment: Okay, I changed basically the whole post, can u figure out what the problem is now?

Comment: It worked, thank you so much, for your help! c:

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to do you're probably missing intents.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='&', intents=intents)  # renamed bot because you're using an instance of Bot



@bot.command()  # pass_context is not necesary since more than few versions back
async def test(ctx, user_id):  # renamed id to user_id to make it more readable
  user = bot.get_user(user_id)
  print(user)

TOKEN = ""
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Take into consideration the code above retreives a "user" object not a "member". The distinction is important if your leaderboard is related to a specific server. Also, the user object doen't have attributes such as "roles", "nickname", etc. If you wish to retreive that information you need to get a member object using `ctx.guild.get_member` instead of `bot.get_user`