# discord bot python I want to get a nick from ID

Tags: python

```
@app.command()
async def mix(ctx):

    # print(ctx.author.voice and ctx.author.voice.channel)    

    if ctx.author.voice and ctx.author.voice.channel:

        global count

        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel

        mem_keys = channel.voice_states.keys()
        user_key = putList(mem_keys)
        user_name = []
        for u in user_key:
            tmp = await app.fetch_user(int(u)) # find user's id
            user_name.append(tmp.name) # This doesn't return a 'nick', it only returns a 'name'.
```

I want to print out a nick, not a name, in the code above. What should I do?

++++++++++
I'm sorry, I've added content

I tried to get nicknames for users in the guild with user ID.
But I could only get a name, not a nick. How can I get a nick?

Comment: Hey, you're missing a few key pieces of info that we need in order to be able to answer this question! For example, what package are you using, and what is the expected output / what you've tried / what output you're currently getting?

Comment: your example is not clear.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've added content

Comment: This might be helpful: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.display_name

Comment: Can I get an example? @knosmos

Comment: this may be help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54499864/discord-py-get-user-object-from-id-tag)