# How can I send a message to a user out of a JSON file?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Probably a very easy question to answer, but I want to send a message to a user after a certain time. For this I read his ID from a JSON. Problem with this? You cannot append a `send` to a `str` or this error is then spit out.

I have already tried to convert the whole thing, but without success. Can someone give me a hint here?

**The code:**

```py
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        period = 10 # 86400.0
        while 3:
            with open('work_data/statues.json') as j:
                u_data = json.load(j)
                for user in list(u_data.keys()): # read user, ID comes out if you do print(user)
                    if dt.datetime.now().timestamp() - u_data[user][0]['last_seen'] >= period:
                        await user.send(f"{user}, you haven't shown up at work for 24 hours and have been fired.") # part that doesn't work
                        await asyncio.sleep(2)
                        u_data.pop(user)
                        write_json(u_data)
                await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
```

**The JSON:**

```py
{
    "30288509151923XXXX": [ # Last 4 numbers removed because privacy.
        {
# rest not relevant
        }
    ]
}
```

**The error message:**

```py
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mike\PycharmProjects\MikeBot\venv\lib\site-packages\disnake\client.py", line 505, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mike\PycharmProjects\MikeBot\cogs\work.py", line 308, in on_ready
    await user.send(f"{user}, you haven't shown up at work for 24 hours and have been fired.")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Comment: you haven't shown the complete code

Comment: @omargamal The rest of the code is not relevant as just the event is not working. I showed the whole `on_ready` code which needs to be taken into account.

Comment: can you show the error message?

Comment: @FusionSid Added the error message, thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py get user object from id/tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54499864/discord-py-get-user-object-from-id-tag)

Comment: @esqew I have looked at this post before, unluckily not. I do not quite understand what the bot reads out the ID if I `print(user)` but in the next step is not able to send a message to this ID. I guess the process of reforming is my problem here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using `disnake` instead of `discord.py`.

You can have a look at their docs. Here we learn something about [fetch_user](https://docs.disnake.dev/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fetch%20user#disnake.Client.fetch_user), [get_user](https://docs.disnake.dev/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#disnake.ext.commands.Bot.get_user) or [getch_user](https://docs.disnake.dev/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#disnake.ext.commands.Bot.getch_user) which will first check the cache and then fetch the user if needed.

**In your example, you can use the following:**

```py
await self.bot.getch_user(user) # asynchronous, needs to be awaited
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you can’t send a message to a number it needs to be sent to a user.

Instead of:

```
await user.send(f"{user}, you haven't shown up at work for 24 hours and have been fired.")
```

Try:

```
_user = await self.client.fetch_user(int(user))
await _user.send(f"{user}, you haven't shown up at work for 24 hours and have been fired.")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user_object = await bot.fetch_user(<id>)
await user_object.send(<message>)
```

should work in your case!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).